# In Tensorflow, what is difference between name, ^name, and name:digits?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm looking for Tensorflow for adding some node while constructing graph. However I got some errors which is

`Node (some node) : Connecting to invalid output 1 of source node (my new node) which has 1 outputs`

I found that the error is occurred in `Convert()` function in `graph_constructor.cc`. I thought the reason was related to operation type I made, but when I navigate the some code in tensorflow, I found function called `ParseTensorName()`. According to explanation in the function,

`Parse either a name, ^name, or name:digits....`

I have no idea the difference between three things. Can I get some explanation? or advice related to the error above?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're right. it seems similar to that question. Thanks!!

Comment: It's an exact duplicate. The digit is explained over there and the "^name" is just a regex expression.